# Elegant way of killing a Linux program

Tags: linux, kill-process

I am running a Linux program that uses a lot of memory. If I terminate it manually using Ctrl-C, it will do the necessary memory clean-up. Now I'm trying to terminate the program using a script. What is an elegant way to do so? I'm hoping to do something similar to Ctrl-C so it can do the memory clean-up. Will using the "kill -9" command do this?

Comment: Don't do `kill -9`. That is extremely rude to the application. A normal `kill` should do what Ctrl-C does.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by memory clean-up?
Keep in mind that memory will be freed anyway, regardless of the killing signal.

Default kill signal - SIGTERM (15) gives application a chance to do some additional work but it has to be implemented with a signal handler.

[Signal handling in c++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm)